# compare string date to current date

Tags: ios, timezone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Hello i have a problem i have a value(date value) from server and i have to check that value with current date and to see which one is greater .i am using the following code but it also shows second date is greater ..how to solve this.It always come to else block.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *dateOfEvent=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-04 03:22:55"];


if([dateOfEvent compare:[NSDate date]]==NSOrderedAscending)
{
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Event has    been passed." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    return;
}
else
{

   }
```

Comment: Make your date format string match the format of the date string.

Comment: What do you get if you NSLog dateOfEvent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the date properly, the formatter has to have the same format as the string. If your string is "2013-04-04", then your date formatter should be "yyyy-MM-dd:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];

NSDate *dateOfEvent=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-04-04"];
```

Comment: i have changed the question plz see it.

Comment: they are still different, there are 2 blank spaces between the day and the hour

Comment: it is typing mistake actually one space are in both.

Comment: Print the value of dateOfEvent and check if it has a date after creating it

Comment: when i try tp print current date it logs 2013-10-30 23:55:39 +0000  and the current time is 6:35 PM I able to get the dateOfEvent but problem is when comapring to current date.

Comment: please comapre  current it with a passed date and it will come to else in that case also.

Comment: Use NSOrderedDescending then in the comparer, I tried and it works

Answer (score 0):

Convert both dates in same format. Then compare as follows:

```
if (serverDate.timeIntervalSince1970 > currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970) {
// Server date is greater. Do your stuff

}
else {
// Current date is greater. Do your stuff
}
```

Hope this helps.